# VB.NET overloading array access?

Tags: vb.net, operator-overloading, overloading

Is it possible to overload the array/dict access operators in VB.net? For example, you can state something like:

```
Dim mydict As New Hashtable()
mydict.add("Cool guy", "Overloading is dangerous!")
mydict("Cool guy") = "Overloading is cool!"
```

And that works just fine. But what I would like to do is be able to say:

```
mydict("Cool guy") = "3"
```

and then have 3 automagically converted to the Integer 3.

I mean, sure I can have a private member mydict.coolguy and have setCoolguy() and getCoolguy() methods, but I would *prefer* to be able to write it the former way if at all possible.

Thanks

---

To clarify - I want to be able to "do stuff" with the value. So for instance, say I have

```
myclass.fizzlesticks ' String type
myclass.thingone     ' Numerical type, say integer
```

and then I want to be able to write

```
myclass("thingummy") = "This is crazy"
```

which fires off a method that looks like this

```
Private sub insanitea(Byval somarg as Object, Byval rhs as Object)
    If somearg = "thingummy" And rhs = "This is crazy" Then
        thingone = 4
        fizzlesticks = rhs & " and cool too!"
    End If
End Sub
```

This isn't the precise use-case, but I think it does a better job of being able to illustrate what I'm looking for?

Comment: I took a stab at what you are asking, but not sure the title of the question and what I read coorespond.  Let me know if I am way off base here.

Comment: That's probably about as accurate as my example, and if that were all I needed, then your solution would work perfectly fine. I just want some slightly more complicated behavior in my class, i.e. on assignment I want to be able to convert the values if they're not already what they should be. If that makes any sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't overload the array access operators in Visual Basic.

[Currently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613(VS.80).aspx) the only operators you can overload are:

```
Unary operators:
+   -   Not   IsTrue   IsFalse   CType

Binary operators:
+   -   *   /   \   &   Like   Mod   And   Or   Xor
^   <<   >>   =   <>   >   <   >=   <=
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do the following:

```
mydict("Cool guy") = 3 //without quotes
```

Then you can do

```
dim x =  mydict("Cool guy") + 7

//x returns 10
```

Or, you could do a Int32.tryParse

```
dim x as integer
if int32.tryParse(mydict("Cool guy"), x) then
     return x + 7 //would return 10
end if
```